# Spiral graphs for time series data in python

Tags: python, plot, visualization

I have a time series data at a 10 minute interval over several days. I would like to plot this data in python like a spiral graph that looks like a clock over 24 hours (the circle's radius is 24 hours)The days as concentric circles in this case the start date 2019-10-08 as inner most circle and 2019-10-09 as next circle and so on. The Values should be color coded based on the 'Value' column. The spiral graph should look something like this
[spiral graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8GzR.png)
Can anyone help me with this??

```
TimeStampLocal   Value  
       2019-10-08 14:30:00     8
       2019-10-08 14:40:00    19
       2019-10-08 14:50:00    14
       2019-10-08 15:00:00    22
       2019-10-08 15:10:00    11
       2019-10-08 15:20:00     9
       2019-10-08 15:30:00     6
       2019-10-08 15:40:00     7
       2019-10-08 15:50:00     9
       2019-10-08 16:00:00    19
       2019-10-08 16:10:00     7
       2019-10-08 16:20:00    19
       2019-10-08 16:30:00     9
       2019-10-08 16:40:00    95
       2019-10-08 16:50:00    64
       2019-10-08 17:00:00    23
       2019-10-08 17:10:00    12
       2019-10-08 17:20:00    17
       2019-10-08 17:30:00    68
       2019-10-08 17:40:00     6
       2019-10-08 17:50:00     9
       2019-10-08 18:00:00    27
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Although it is not the nicest program and might need some refactoring.

But it works and shows the general idea behind transforming timestamps to radial coordinates and displaying them on a canvas.

```
import time
import math
from tkinter import *


class Spiralplot(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, d = [], width = 500, height=500):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        top=self.winfo_toplevel() #Flexible Toplevel of the window
        top.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        top.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid(sticky=N+S+W+E)

        x,y = int(width/2),int(height/2)
        
        self.plotregion = Canvas(self,width=width,height=height,bg="#ffffff")
        self.plotregion.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.plotregion.create_line(x-10,y,x+10,y)
        self.plotregion.create_line(x,y-10,x,y+10)

        lines = []
        for p in d:
            xpos = x+math.cos(p[3])*p[2]
            ypos = y+math.sin(p[3])*p[2]
            lines.append((xpos,ypos,p[4]))

        if len(lines)>0:
            for i in range(len(lines)-1):
                print(lines[i][0],lines[i][1],lines[i+1][0],lines[i+1])
                self.plotregion.create_line(lines[i][0],lines[i][1],lines[i+1][0],lines[i+1][1],
                                           fill=lines[i][2],width=2)

def rainbow(x):
    ## Compute rainbow color from a number between 0 and 1
    if x >1:x=1
    if x <0:x=0
    red = math.cos(x*2*math.pi)+0.5
    green = math.cos((x+.66)*2*math.pi)+.05
    blue = math.cos((x+.33)*2*math.pi)+0.5
    outstr = '#'
    for v in [red,green,blue]:
        if v > 1:
            outstr+="ff"
        elif v < 0:
            outstr+="00"
        else:
            h = hex(int(v*255)).split('x')[-1]
            if len(h)==1:
                outstr+="0"+h
            else:
                outstr+=h
    return outstr

def position(tstamp, firstday="2019-10-07",r1=100,step=20):
    ## Transforms a timestamp to radial coordinates. Add a first day and its radius to customize
    ## r1: Radius of the first day
    ## step: Step in radius between days
    
    tfirst = time.strptime(firstday,"%Y-%m-%d")
    t = time.strptime(tstamp,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    
    daytime = (t[3]+t[4]/60)/24
    delta_d = (time.mktime(t)-time.mktime(tfirst))//(24*3600)

    radius = r1 + (delta_d+daytime)*step
    angle = daytime*2*math.pi

    return (radius, angle)

def add_coordinates(data):
     
    for i in range(len(data)):
        p = position(data[i][0])
        col = rainbow(data[i][1]/100)
        data[i] = (data[i][0],data[i][1],p[0],p[1],col)

    return data
    

labels = ("TS", "Value")
data = [("2019-10-08 14:30:00",8),
        ("2019-10-08 14:40:00",19),
        ("2019-10-08 14:50:00",14),
        ("2019-10-08 15:00:00",22),
        ("2019-10-08 15:10:00",11),
        ("2019-10-08 15:20:00",9),
        ("2019-10-08 15:30:00",6),
        ("2019-10-08 15:40:00",7),
        ("2019-10-08 15:50:00",9),
        ("2019-10-08 16:00:00",19),
        ("2019-10-08 16:10:00",7),
        ("2019-10-08 16:20:00",19),
        ("2019-10-08 16:30:00",9),
        ("2019-10-08 16:40:00",95),
        ("2019-10-08 16:50:00",64),
        ("2019-10-08 17:00:00",23),
        ("2019-10-08 17:10:00",12),
        ("2019-10-08 17:20:00",17),
        ("2019-10-08 17:30:00",68),
        ("2019-10-08 17:40:00",6),
        ("2019-10-08 17:50:00",9),
        ("2019-10-08 18:00:00",27)]

data = add_coordinates(data)

root = Tk()
plot = Spiralplot(root,d = data)
root.mainloop()
```

The output of the example data you offered, would be:

[image]

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for the reply. I was able to plot more data (over several days) in spirals. But I would like to plot the data just like a clock, plotting 12.AM data in the top and so on... something like in this https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8GzR.png . And I also would like to have a color coding with a legend instead of random colors, say 0-10 in green 10-20 yellow 20-50 red and so on

Comment: Not a problem. Just subtract `math.pi/2` from the angle to rotate the plot and get 12AM at the top. And the `rainbow()` function is just an example that converts numbers to colors. If you want a fixed table, just change the line in `add_coordinates()` that gets the color. You can replace it by an if-elif-else block to get a table of colors.